# how to animate image & change the direction from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Please find the code, which iam facing issue with changing the direction of arrow, the arrow should change the facing from right to left once it reach the screen width. THE REQUIRED FUNCTIONALITY IS THE ARROW SHOULD NOT GO IN REVERSE it has to change its direction.

tried lot some one give solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/7xyuqe1k/5/

```
function AnimateFish() {

        var Fish3 = $("[id^=fish]").not(".HoverFish"),

            theContainer = $("#container"),
            maxLeft = theContainer.width() - Fish3.width() - 50,
            maxTop = theContainer.height() - Fish3.height(),
            leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
            topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 100,
            imgRight = "Assets/fish-glow3-right.gif",
            imgLeft = "Assets/fish-glow3.gif";

        /*Get position of the fish*/
        //console.log(Fish3.position().left +" +"+leftPos);
        //alert(Fish3.position().left);

        if ($("[id^=fish]").position().left >= leftPos) {
            $(this).css("background-image", 'url("' + imgRight + '")');
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-image", 'url("' + imgLeft + '")');
        }

        Fish3.animate({
            "left": leftPos,
            "top": topPos
        }, 1800, AnimateFish);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem on fish's destination points(positions left & top) picking. First fish works properly since it's picking the destination point respective to itself, but rest of the fishes also were taking the destination points respective to 1st fish not themselves.

The working sample is available here http://jsfiddle.net/ravinila/7xyuqe1k/26/

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var newfishid = 0;

    $('.post-button').click( function(e) {  

        var fish = $("<div/>", {"class":"large-fish fish", "id" : "fish"+(newfishid++)});

        $('#container').append(fish);

        fish.on("anim", function(e){
            var _this = $(this),
            theContainer = $("#container"),
            maxLeft = theContainer.width() - _this.width() - 50,
            maxTop = theContainer.height() - _this.height(),
            leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
            topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 100,
            imgLeft = "http://free-icon-download.com/modules/PDdownloads/images/screenshots/free-icon-download_left-arrow-blue.png",
            imgRight = "http://www.newclassicdesign.com/r_arrow.png";
            if (_this.position().left < leftPos) {
                _this.css("background-image", 'url("' + imgRight + '")');
            } else {
                _this.css("background-image", 'url("' + imgLeft + '")');
            }

            _this.animate({
                "left": leftPos,
                "top": topPos
            }, 2500, function(){
                $(this).trigger("anim");
            });
        });
        fish.trigger("anim");

        fish.hover(function(e) {
            $(this).stop();
        }, function(e) {
            $(this).trigger("anim");
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at it and it looks like its a silly mistake. Your fiddle showed something was working since it changed something when the direction changed, so the basics are okay. You just forgot that there was an image tag inside you div that you're meant to be manipulating.

```
function AnimateFish() {

    var Fish3 = $("#fish1").not(".HoverFish"),

    theContainer = $("#container"),
    maxLeft = theContainer.width() - Fish3.width() - 50,
    maxTop = theContainer.height() - Fish3.height(),
    leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxLeft),
    topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxTop) + 100;
    imgRight = "http://www.newclassicdesign.com/r_arrow.png",
    imgLeft = "http://free-icon-download.com/modules/PDdownloads/images/screenshots/free-icon-download_left-arrow-blue.png";


// below here you used $(Fish3), but Fish3 is already a JS object - you don't need to rewrap it. 
// The biggest problem however, is that below that you used '$(this)', which won't work as there
// is no context defined (you're in an if, not a jQuery function). 
// Replacing this with the same Fish3 does the job,
// as it already was a jQuery object anyhow.

// I have also changed your background from an image to red and green for testing purposes.
// As you can see, thats working. However, your image isn't changing.. 
// This is because you have an image inside you wrapper which you aren't changing.

    if (Fish3.position().left >= leftPos) {
        Fish3.css("background", 'green');
// So lets change the image...
        Fish3.find("img").attr("src", imgLeft);
    } else {
        Fish3.css("background", 'red');
// So lets change the image...
        Fish3.find("img").attr("src", imgRight);
    }

    Fish3.animate({
        "left": leftPos,
        "top": topPos
    }, 1800, AnimateFish);
}
```

Check my comments inside the code to see what happened, but copying this into your fiddle and replacing the animation function did the trick.